# Sandwich measurable set between Borel sets

Tags: measure-theory

If $B$ is Lebesgue measurable then we can sandwich it closely between Borel sets in the sense that there is Borel $A , C$ such that
$A \subset B \subset C$ and $m(C\setminus A) = 0$.

does anyone know a reference for this statement or how to go about a proof? this is something that was skipped over in class with no proof, not graded homework, but I marked it homework anyway =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that $E$ is Lebesgue Measurable if and only if $\forall \delta > 0$, there is an open set $E\subset U$ sucht that $m(U\setminus E)<\frac{\delta}{2}$, it's easy to prove it : First, note that if $E$ is Lebesgue Measurable, then $E^{c}$ is also Lebesgue Measurable and so, there is another open set $E^{c}\subset V$ such that $m(V\setminus E^{c})<\frac{\delta}{2}$. Now, it's easy to see that there is an open set ($U$) and a closed set ($V^{c}$), such that $V^{c}\subset E\subset U$ and such that $m(U\setminus V)<\delta$. At this point, just choose for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ open sets $U_{n}$ and closed sets $F_{n}$ such that $F_{n}\subset E \subset U_{n}$ and that $m(U_{n}\setminus F_{n})<\frac{1}{n}$. Now, just take $A = \cup F_{n}$ and $B= \cap U_{n}$, both Borel sets and it's trivial to see that $A \subset E\subset B$ and that $m(B\setminus A)=0$.

Comment: sorry for the sucessive edits. now i think there is no typo

Comment: thanks. don't worry about the edits your post is very clear!